# Password Protected Directory [cPanel] - Receiving no Login Prompt and Error 401

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, password-protection, .htpasswd

I have customized error pages setup on my site for the 302, 401, 403, 404 and 500 HTTP error codes. The five custom error page files are stored in the home directory.

I would also like to protect a specific directory with a password and have tried doing so with cPanel's "Password Protect Directories" feature.

I should also mention that in the home directory, there is an `.htaccess` file, with the following:

```
<limit GET POST PUT>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</limit>

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 302 /302.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
```

With that out of the way, I can now explain what's currently happening with this setup. Essentially, rather than the web browser prompting for the username and password, the password-protected page simply goes straight to the `401.php` error page.

I've tried moving the error pages to their own directory, `/error/`, I've tried using cPanel's own error page setup tool (which uses `.shtml` files), and I've also tried a combination of cPanel's error pages and my own.

From my testing, it seems that cPanel's `.shtml` error pages work, but they are ugly and don't match the theme of the website. The error pages I made, use PHP to require files for the theme, as well as to echo back the user's requested URL.

I also seemingly had the combination of both sets of error pages working, even after I reuploaded the home directory's `.htaccess` file, but upon removing the set that cPanel made, everything broke again. I also don't know if it's good practice to use two sets of error pages, as follows:

```
<HOME_DIR>
--- <DIR>
    --- .htaccess (contains code for password protection)
    --- index.php
--- .htaccess (links to PHP error pages)
--- 302.php
--- 302.shtml
--- 401.php
--- 401.shtml
--- 403.php
--- 403.shtml
--- 404.php
--- 404.shtml
--- 500.php
--- 500.shtml
--- index.php
```

This is something that I've never experienced before. From what I can ascertain, the problem is coming from the `.htaccess` file under the home directory, but I'm not 100% on that.

Lastly, here is the `.htaccess` file that cPanel created when I set up the password protection (note: "<USER>" and "<DIR>" have been used for privacy) :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "/home/<USER>/.htpasswds/public_html/<DIR>/passwd"
require valid-user
```

It's an Apache server, by the way. Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: I can't get your question. Please ask it clearly.

Comment: @Greg Sorry, I tried to keep it clear while including everything I thought would be necessary to answer it. Essentially, I have my own error pages that I'm using, with the `.htaccess` file that I have posted (the first piece of code), and I've also password-protected a directory from within cPanel. That directory's `.htaccess` file is the last piece of code. Instead of being given two fields for the username and password in the web browser, the page simply goes to the `401.php` "Authentication Failed/Unauthorized Access" error page, and I don't know why it's doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **An Indirect Solution**

It appears that I've had to convert the error page files from .`php` to .`shtml` format. Along with that, all PHP `require` statements have been removed in favor of plain HTML (as I couldn't get them working, not even with SSI's `#include` statement), and lastly I've had to replace the PHP `echo` for the requested URL in favor of an SSI `#echo`.

This was more work than necessary for such a mundane thing. I have no idea why PHP conflicted with password-protected directories. This hasn't happened before as I've used PHP error pages in the past. It must be some kind of conflict between PHP and the password protection.

Well, for what it's worth, there's a 'solution'.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary rename .htaccess file in which you have added ErrorDocument rule and then clear your browser cache and cookies. Now try to access your password protected URL. If it works, copy your ErrorDocument code and add it after password protection rules.

Comment: Hi there. I assume you meant copy the `ErrorDocument` code to end of the `.htaccess` file inside the protected directory? If not, could you elaborate, please? I have tried doing this, and while it appears to be working in my main browser, the page results in loading the `401.php` error page when I try it in Incognito Mode.

Comment: Copy ErrorDocument code from /home/<user>/.htaccess file to bottom of /home/<user>/public_html/.htaccess file.

Comment: There already is one there. I don't have any `.htaccess` file outside of `public_html`. A solution I've found is to simply remove all PHP requires from my error page files, and convert them to `.shtml` format. The entire site is now running off those. I also had to change the PHP to echo the requested URL into an SSI comment.